# ARB_shader_image_load_store creates synchronization artefacts

Tags: opengl, synchronization, glsl

My glsl code:

```
    ivec2 readCoord = ivec2(gl_FragCoord);
    readCoord.x += int(sin(time) * 100);
    vec2 c = imageLoad(image, readCoord).rg;
    memoryBarrier();
    imageStore(image, ivec2(gl_FragCoord), vec4(c, 0, 0));
```

`time` is an uniform of type float.

A frame from the animation:

[image]

And here's how it's supposed to look:

[image]

Any idea what's going on? :)

Note: In [this demo](https://github.com/Erkaman/image-load-store-demo/blob/master/src/main.cpp) they do the same thing as me, and they don't even use memoryBarrier(). Same in [this example](https://github.com/progschj/OpenGL-Examples/blob/master/12shader_image_load_store.cpp)

Comment: What exactly is this code trying to do? You seem to be doing a read/modify/write to the same image, but you're writing to a different location in the image than you read, in some way based on `sin(time)`. How exactly do you expect that to work? And what are you rendering with this shader? How are you displaying/reading the resulting image? And lots of other questions.

Comment: @NicolBolas This is a simplified version of my real code. I'm intentionally reading from a different pos than the one I'm writing into. What this code does is simply shift the input left and right smoothly in a never-ending animation. I'm displaying the resulting image with 2 triangles in a VBO, with a shader that uses the `texture()` function.

Comment: And are you properly using barriers between the shader doing this and the shader displaying the image? During your shader, are you *certain* that *no fragment* reads from a location that *any other fragment* writes to? Because the way it looks, if you are rendering a wider area than `sin(time)`, then some fragments are going to read from locations that others are writing to.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I do `glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);` right between the two shaders.  About your second question - yes, some fragments are going to do that. That's why I have the memoryBarrier() in the shader.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I edited the question.

Comment: The `memoryBarrier()` call will not help you at all for your use case. You have concurrent memory accesses which you simply _can't_ synchronize that way, and your complete approach seems doomed.

Comment: @derhass: I believe that `memoryBarrier()`  will make GL execute all reads (for the current triangle), and when it has done so for all the reads, only then it will go on with the writes. If this is not true, can you point me to a reference that explains what memoryBarrier really does?

Comment: @derhass: Quote from GLSL standard: "The order of memory accesses performed by one shader invocation, as observed by other
shader invocations, [...] can be controlled through memory control functions."

Comment: But that quote is completely irrelevant to your issue. The `memoryBarrier` function only control what reads and stores are _issued_ by the local invocation. It will not prevent another concurrent invocation to already have issued both the load and the store, before your invocation even starts. THe ordering between the invocations itself is still completely undefined. For your use case, you need a global synchronization barrier for all fragment shader invocations of your particular draw call - and there is simply no such thing in the GL.

Comment: The closest you can get to such a synchronization is the `barrier()` function, but that is only for tesselation and compute shaders - and it will apply to all invocations for a single patch or work group, respectively, but never globally. The easiest solution to your problem seems to be to simply not update the image in-place, but just use two different images.